# How to update to KDE Plasma 5.9?

Tags: plasma, kde5

I am new to the Ubuntu world. I have downloaded Kubuntu 16.04 LTS and it installed really nicely. Now, I see that it just comes with KDE 5.5.5.

I have added the stable repo and am now having the 5.8.5 version.
Having just read about the KDE 5.9 release I am wondering - how to get it?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use the latest from KDE you could use KDE Neon instead of Kubuntu, which is Ubuntu LTS with the latest KDE.

You can get KDE Neon at: https://neon.kde.org/

There are two different versions to choose from.

- A User Edition, featuring the latest officially released KDE software on a stable base. Ideal for everyday users.
- A Developer Edition, featuring pre-release KDE software.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Answer (score 4):

It's not in backports PPA yet (as of 6th February). You can see it on launchpad https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports/+packages?field.name_filter=plasma&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter= . Just sit tight and wait until it gets added

Comment: thank you. didn't know it'll take them so long

Answer (score 3):

To install the latest official version of Plasma, we have to use [Kubuntu (Backports) repositories](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports). To do this you simply I execute the following in the terminal

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```

This PPA can be added to your system manually by copying the lines below and adding them to your system's software sources.

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE main
```

to see the changes it is to reboot.

Comment: Thank you. I have already managed to update to Plasma 5.8.5. As of today, Plasma 5.9 is released and my question is how to upgrade? The repository only gives me 5.8.5